# How to get a theme tab in the Appearance application?

Tags: themes, xfce, desktop-environments, appearance

I read, in order to change a theme for **xfce4** one has to copy the downloaded theme into **/usr/share/themes** and then select it inside the **Appear** application under the theme tab.

However, there is no theme tab in mine, there are only four tabs:

1. Style
2. Icons
3. Fonts
4. Settings

Answer (score 1):

Xfce 4's appearance settings had no *Theme* tab in it. In fact, it only has 4 tabs you mentioned in the question and it isn't a fault.

Here is a screenshot from my system verifying that, so no need to worry.

[image: XFCE4 appearance settings]

If you're asking this so that you can change the theme quickly, you can just try this command line way instead.

```
xfconf-query  -c xsettings -p /Net/IconThemeName -s theme-name-here
```

Comment: In addition, we can select themes in `System Settings > Window Manger > Style-tab`, this will have influence on the Window decoration and button-layout.